# ORA-00904 Invalid Identifier on decode oracle function

Tags: oracle, plsql

I wrote a simple pl\sql procedure to read a value on db. For the same value I use two different function to have at the end to different value.

My code

```
  begin
    select TRIM(SUBSTR(RPAD(VAL,30,'N'),1,1)),DECODE(TRIM(SUBSTR(RPAD(VAL,30,'N'),2,2)),'S',TRUE,FALSE)
    into va_flag, amount_zero
    from ENV
    where USER = 'C' and VARIABLE = 'FLAG_BALANCE';
    exception
        when others then
          amount_zero := FALSE;
          va_flag := 'N';
  end;
```

When I compile the procedure, I've got the error message :"ORA-00904 "FALSE" Invalid Identifier" on decode function.
amount_zero is a boolean.

Comment: What you've shown is not a complete PL/SQL block. but just a snippet. Please edit to show the entire thing . . . especially the declarations of v_flag and amount_zero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it won't work *straightforward*; the first step will have to be a select into some other datatype (`varchar2` whose value is `Y`/`N` or `T`/`F`; or a `number` with `1`/`0` ... pick any you want) and then switch to a Boolean, in a separate statement. For example:

```
SQL> declare
  2    va_flag          varchar2(1);
  3    amount_zero      boolean;
  4    amount_zero_char varchar2(10);
  5  begin
  6    -- first select it into a VARCHAR2 variable ...
  7    select decode(1, 1, 'T', 'F'),
  8           'N'
  9      into amount_zero_char,
 10           va_flag
 11      from env
 12      where cuser = 'C'
 13        and variable = 'FLAG_BALANCE';
 14
 15    -- ... then switch to Boolean
 16    amount_zero := case when amount_zero_char = 'T' then true
 17                        else false
 18                   end;
 19
 20    -- display it
 21    dbms_output.put_line(case when amount_zero then 'it is true'
 22                              else 'it is false'
 23                         end);
 24  end;
 25  /
it is true

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution...Both solutions are interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle SQL cannot work directly with boolean data type (PL/SQL can but not SQL).

You should try to replace boolean literals with another data type for example VARCHAR2 (and adapt related code):

```
select 
TRIM(SUBSTR(RPAD(VAL,30,'N'),1,1)),
DECODE(TRIM(SUBSTR(RPAD(VAL,30,'N'),2,2)),'S','TRUE','FALSE')
into va_flag, amount_zero
from ENV
```

Comment: The OP's use of BEGIN ... END, with SELECT ... INTO, would suggest he _is_ using PL/SQL, but simply didn't show the entire procedure.

Comment: Yes but if you try to compile OP's code you will see that ORA-904 is returned for line using 'FALSE' with DECODE function: you cannot use boolean values as returned values with DECODE; that's the error root cause.

Comment: yes, of course...I will use a varchar2. I've decide to not use booelan in my code.